# Use of OR in bash

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, brackets, modulo

I want to assign a variable based upon the modulo of another variable (subject number, in this case), getting a number (representing subject condition) which cycles over N conditions.

In other words, I want something very similar to the modular function `a%n`, but for full multiples of `n` I want to return `n`, rather than `0`.

I think the easiest way to do this is with an or conditional, such that if the mod function returns 0, N will be returned instead, but I can't get the syntax to work.

```
subj=4
list=$((subj%4)) || 4
echo $list
```

just returns the result of `subj%4`, and ignores the conditional, while replacing `||` with `-o` fails.

If I try and use brackets around the whole thing, I just get a binary output of the conditional test.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your idea is right, you just put the block inside construct used for running C-style arithmetic operations i.e. use the [Arithmetic expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) operator

```
((list = n%4==0 ? 4 : 0 ))
```

Using a variable and a function separately as OP had asked for

```
modulo() {
    local n="${1?Needs an argument}"
    echo $((n%4==0 ? 4 : 0 ))
}
```

Modify this function to return custom values as you need.

---

```
modulo 5
0    
modulo 4
4    
modulo 8
4
modulo
bash: 1: Needs an argument
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great!

What I was actually looking for is `(( list = n%4==0 ? 4 : subj%4 ))`, but your answer got me there :)

Do you have a source for this `? :` syntax? I cannot find one anywhere, and for obvious reasons it's difficult to search for..

Comment: @HenryBrice: It is a standard C style ternary operator. You can use them in `bash` under `$((..))`

Answer (score 1):

In bash, your `||` means: "If `$((subj%4))` returns non-zero, do `4`".

It will not work, at least because `$((subj%4))` returns zero (exit code, i mean).

In your case, do something like that:

```
subj=4
list=$((subj%4))
if [ "${list}" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "4"
else
    echo "${list}"
fi
```

Comment: @Aserre i'm not. `||` means that right part of the code will be executed if only it's left part finished with non-zero return code. In OP's situation, `$?` is `0` every time. So, right part of his code will never be executed. Edited my post a bit, may be it was written not clearly for understanding.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite? If the right hand returns zero then the left hand should be evaluated?

Is there not a less clunky way to this, than having a whole `if` block? It feels like there should be some way to one-line this?

Comment: @HenryBrice for exit codes in Unix, 0 is a success, 1 or another value is a failure.

Comment: Ahhh... that explains a lot! Thanks :)

As you can tell, I'm something of a noob to bash scripting...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version without branching:

```
$((  1 + (n + m - 1)  % m ))
```

I doubt that branching is an issue in a bash script but that could be useful in other cases.

Example:

```
cycle() { 
    n=$1; m=$2; 
    $(( 1 + (n + m - 1)  % m )) 
} 

for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do echo $i: $(cycle $i 4); done
```

Output:

```
0: 4
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 1
6: 2
7: 3
8: 4
9: 1
```